# Statically built python code cannot resolve DNS names

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns, urllib, urllib3

I'm trying to deploy code to a server to which I don't have root access. So the solution I was thinking was to deploy using [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) and [staticx](https://github.com/JonathonReinhart/staticx).

My code runs in python 3.7, in a nutshell, does something like:

```py
import requests
response = requests.get('http://example.com/api/action')
# Do something with the response
```

When I run it in my environment, even after "building" with `pyinstaller` and `staticx`, it works flawlessly.

However, when I try to deploy it (the server is running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4, which does not have python 3), I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
  File "site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
  File "socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 355, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1229, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 956, in send
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 183, in connect
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f912ca96f28>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
  File "site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='someserver.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/action (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f912ca96f28>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

Everything works if I use IP addresses instead of domains. Unfortunately, it's not a possibility because I have to hit an proxy that uses hosts. Also IP addresses may change in the future.

The server resolves names perfectly fine if I use `nslookup` or `ping`.

Any ideas why this could be happening? Any alternatives on how I could deploy my code in a way that it works in the remote server may also be a valid answer. Note however:

- I have no root access and requesting the installation of python3, any libs or any other package such as docker, etc would most likely be rejected by my customer
- The server can resolve external names, such as `google.com` but does not have access to the outer internet (the code is ment to work on internal servers, with internal DNS such as `someserver.mycustomer.example`)

Comment: Can you resolve (`dig`/`host`) the hostname used in your script? Is that actual backtrace, because it appears your `requests.get()` call is directed to `someserver.com` which sounds possible wrong / example code?

Comment: Indeed it is example code. My actual code uses an internal domain name that I cannot publish here. But yes, dig and nslookup can resolve the name.

Comment: Hey there, did you ever find a solution for this? I have the exact same problem :(